# Avoid me to create 8 addEventListener in a script

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just a javascript's beginner and I need your help to optimize my code.

Here the fact, when i click on this div :

```
<div class="sectionGrid__div--circle" id="lightboxBut_1">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100?mountain" alt="Mountain">
</div>
```

This script is activated :

```
document.getElementById("lightboxBut_1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("lightboxBut_1");

    let lightbox_1 = document.getElementById("lightboxOpen_1"); 
    lightbox_1.style.display = "block";
});
```

And finally it displays a div on the screen :

```
<div class="lightbox__container">
   <div class="lightbox__container--left">
      <h3 class="sstitleStyle">Lightbox 1</h3>
      <p class="paraStyle">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat culpa neque dicta unde, repellendus consectetur a sit autem perspiciatis tempore quasi odio earum ipsam assumenda. Aspernatur vel iure earum ad!</p>
   </div>
   <div class="lightbox__container--right">
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/500x500?mountain" alt="">
   </div>
</div>
```

Actually it's working but i need to do that 8 times because i've got 8 buttons which have to display 8 differents div on the screen.
So how i can optimize my script and avoid to do 8 addEventListener ?
Thank you a lot for your help !!

Comment: Actually, you've got it backwards. The `.addEventListener()` code is executed first (which registers the event handling function) and then second when the `div` is clicked on, that event handling function executes.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant HTML. Most likely you can leverage ["event delegation"](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and only set up one event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New web developers tend to give most of their HTML elements an `id` because one of the first things you learn is how easy it is to reference that element in JavaScript with `.getElementById()`. Unfortunately, this practice doesn't lend itself to scaling your application and will quickly lead to code duplication and high maintenance as you'll have to add/remove event handlers each time you add or remove new HTML elements.

Instead, `id`s can and should not be used in most circumstances and instead, you can locate your elements by many other methods (CSS class, location in the document relative to other elements are the most common).

So, here's an example with 5 `div` elements that need to be activated each from its own image click, but it doesn't matter how many you wind up having. As you add or remove some from the HTML, the JavaScript will not need to be altered.

This technique leverages ["event delegation"](https://javascript.info/event-delegation), where the fact that events bubble up from their source to the top level of the document object model so that you only set up one handler at a higher level than any element that may trigger the event and you handle it there.

By the way, in the example below, a click on a thumbnail image will unhide the lightbox below it because I'm using `.classList.remove("hidden")`. But, if you were to use `.classList.toggle("hidden")`, each click on the thumbnail would cause the lightbox to hide if it was already being shown and show if it was hidden.

```js
// Here's the key: instead of setting up a hander for each clickable element
// we just set up one at a common ancestor of all the clickable elements and
// wait for the event to bubble up to it and handle it here.

// All DOM event handlers will automatically be passed a reference to the event
// that triggered them so your event handler should be set up to recieve that
// argument. 
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // Check to see if the element that triggered the event is one we care about
  // The event object has a target property that references the actual eleement
  // that was the source for the event in the first place (an <img> with a class
  // of "source" is what we care about).
  if(event.target.classList.contains("source")){
    // It is, so just unhide its next sibling element
    event.target.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden  { display:none; }
```

```html
<div class="sectionGrid__div--circle">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100?mountain" 
       alt="Mountain" class="source">
  
  <!-- By placing the element that is related to the image within the 
       same parent, it becomes very easy to locate it via a relative 
       location reference later. Also note that it has the hidden class
       by default so it will be initially hidden. -->
  <div class="lightbox__container hidden">
    <div class="lightbox__container--left">
      <h3 class="sstitleStyle">Lightbox 1</h3>
      <p class="paraStyle">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
      Fugiat culpa neque dicta unde, repellendus consectetur a sit autem
      perspiciatis tempore quasi odio earum ipsam assumenda. Aspernatur vel iure
      earum ad!</p>
   </div>
   <div class="lightbox__container--right">
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/500x500?mountain" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sectionGrid__div--circle">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100?mountain" 
       alt="Mountain" class="source">
  
  <div class="lightbox__container hidden">
    <div class="lightbox__container--left">
      <h3 class="sstitleStyle">Lightbox 2</h3>
      <p class="paraStyle">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
      Fugiat culpa neque dicta unde, repellendus consectetur a sit autem
      perspiciatis tempore quasi odio earum ipsam assumenda. Aspernatur vel iure
      earum ad!</p>
   </div>
   <div class="lightbox__container--right">
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/500x500?mountain" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sectionGrid__div--circle">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100?mountain" 
       alt="Mountain" class="source">
  
  <div class="lightbox__container hidden">
    <div class="lightbox__container--left">
      <h3 class="sstitleStyle">Lightbox 3</h3>
      <p class="paraStyle">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
      Fugiat culpa neque dicta unde, repellendus consectetur a sit autem
      perspiciatis tempore quasi odio earum ipsam assumenda. Aspernatur vel iure
      earum ad!</p>
   </div>
   <div class="lightbox__container--right">
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/500x500?mountain" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sectionGrid__div--circle">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100?mountain" 
       alt="Mountain" class="source">
  
  <div class="lightbox__container hidden">
    <div class="lightbox__container--left">
      <h3 class="sstitleStyle">Lightbox 4</h3>
      <p class="paraStyle">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
      Fugiat culpa neque dicta unde, repellendus consectetur a sit autem
      perspiciatis tempore quasi odio earum ipsam assumenda. Aspernatur vel iure
      earum ad!</p>
   </div>
   <div class="lightbox__container--right">
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/500x500?mountain" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sectionGrid__div--circle">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/100x100?mountain" 
       alt="Mountain" class="source">

  <div class="lightbox__container hidden">
    <div class="lightbox__container--left">
      <h3 class="sstitleStyle">Lightbox 5</h3>
      <p class="paraStyle">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
      Fugiat culpa neque dicta unde, repellendus consectetur a sit autem
      perspiciatis tempore quasi odio earum ipsam assumenda. Aspernatur vel iure
      earum ad!</p>
   </div>
   <div class="lightbox__container--right">
       <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/500x500?mountain" alt="">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what i need thank a lot for you help Scott Marcus !

Comment: @Ed_ You're welcome Ed. Don't forget to up vote as well and good luck!